# How to build a Main Menu screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Good day (and happy New Year),

I'm a beginner VB.Net programmer using VS 2008.

I'm planning a new winform project whose main form should look more or less like this:

> **MAIN MENU**
>   1. DoSomething1
>   2. DoSomething2
>   3. DoSomething3
>   ...
>
> **Please choose:** [TextBox]

The user can either choose from the Main Menu (by clicking an item) or enter the item number in the textbox. For example, if the user clicks DoSomething3 in the Main Menu (or alternatively enters 3 in the textbox), another form will be opened and hide the main form.

What would be the best way to implement it?
Specifically, I would like to know how I make so that choosing from the menu and entering a number in the textbox fire the same event.

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the traditional user interface for a console mode program.  It is quite inappropriate for a GUI app, the kind that Winforms let you build.  The closest approximation is buttons for each menu item.  So the user can just click one directly, rather than having to type a number.  The keyboard still works too, pressing Tab to move through the buttons, Space to activate one.

Look around a bit at user interfaces of other programs you use.  Note their use of a menu and a toolbar.

Comment: Thanks. My project will have some forms, none of them is appropriate to serve as the main/opening screen of the project, so I thought of the traditional main menu screen in which most of the menu items will open a form hiding the main form. Maybe a toolbar or a menustrip is a better idea...

Answer (score 0):

- [Context Menu and Event Handling in Visual Basic .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ContextMenuVBNET.aspx)

**Edit:**

Ok. I think I did not understand. May these links will help you:

- [Multiple Forms in VB.NET. Part 2 - Accessing Controls on Other Forms](http://devcity.net/PrintArticle.aspx?ArticleID=100)

You can use buttons to goto other forms: Look at this thread:

- [Link from one form to another (Thread)](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread3175.html)

Comment: No, it's not a context menu. The form itself acts as a menu.

Answer (score 0):

it's been almost 2 yrs i did not use vb.net but i'll try to help u.

you can make something very simple.e.g.

Have three buttons on the main menu of the main form e.g.

Button 1
Button 2
Button 3

Add click events to all the tree buttons. Create a method for button1,button2,button3

e.g.

```
void SimulateButton1
{
   SpecifiedForm.show();
}

void SimulateButton2
{
   SpecifiedForm.show();
}

void SimulateButton3
{
   SpecifiedForm.show();
}
```

Now for the main menu its ok, lets consider entering the Number manually

```
//get the number first
String Choice=txtChoiceTextBox.getText();
```

You can add a button next to the textbox with caption Choose Option
and then add an onclick event to this button

on clicking on the button, do the following

```
if (Choice="1")
{
   SimulateButton1();
   return;
}

if (Choice="2")
{
   SimulateButton2();
   return;
}

if (Choice="3")
{
   SimulateButton2();
    return;
}
```

For the first tree button it mentioned, it can not be a button but a menu item but the principle is the same
that's it, hope it helps